# Check if glm::vec3 has be set

Tags: c++, glm-math

If I declare a value as `glm::vec3 myVector;` am I able to just check 
**safely** that it is null by doing a

```
if (!myVector) { 
  setVector(myVector); 
}
```

or is there a way to set `glm::vec3` values to null without having to set each individual value to null

Comment: `glm::vec3` is a vector of 3 floating point elements, it has no concept of __null__.

Comment: @RichardCritten does GLM have some default constructor for it defaults a value to or is it simply just a typedef for 3 floating points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the vector as

```
glm::vec3 myVector;
```

It don't get initialised, you need to declare as:

```
glm::vec3 myVector(0.0);
```

To get properly initialised to 0.

BTW:

```
if (!myVector) { //It is always false, because, it is a reference to a local variable, not a pointer.
```

[Cited](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.20.pdf):

> If there is a single scalar parameter to a vector constructor, it is
>   used to initialize all components of the constructed vector to that
>   scalar’s value.

Comment: what do you suggest instead creating a boolean for checking if it has been set as I don't want to give it a value as all values are possible

Comment: @FrickeFresh I understand what you intend to do, have you found a good answer? I am between having a separate boolean or make a stack with only one element and check if it's empty, sounds like an overkill though.

Comment: @DNax I never found anything, I just refactored my code so I didn't have this hanging declared value and always made sure it was initialised .